# Unconsciousness ending naturally over time?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points, unconscious

In D&D 5E, if a player character, an NPC, or a group of player characters and/or NPCs become unconscious or go critical and then get stabilized, or if an enemy/enemies was/were knocked out instead of killed (PHB p. 198), is there a rule for when they eventually regain consciousness with 1 HP or something?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "go critical".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the *Player’s Handbook* section “Stabilizing a Creature” under **Dropping to 0 Hit Points**:

> A stable creature that isn't healed regains 1 hit point after 1d4 hours.